# Stability of Connecting to a Server Over the Internet with a Public IP Address?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, dns

I just made my server downstairs with a static IP address and set up port forwarding on my router for the specific SSH port that I wanted.

I connected to it using the public ip address supplied from `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip`

I was following this online tutorial (https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-enable-ssh-ubuntu/).

It recommends connecting to this ip address over the internet, but this appears to be the public IP address of the router.

How stable is that ip address and does it change with time?

Would this be an acceptable option if I'm using this as a backup server while I'm out of the country for a month, or should I look into freeDNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your ISP you can have either dynamic or static IP. It's hard to tell which one you have right now - just ask your Internet provider.

But in case it's dynamic you need to set up DDNS service (dynamic DNS), with a domain name, that will be resolved to your current public IP.

And yes, if you're not sure you better use something like freeDNS to set dynamic DNS.

Also make sure that your SSH Server ir properly secured if you want it to be open to the public Internet.

Read these tutorials about SSH hardening:

- https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-openssh-server-best-practices.html

Comment: I have a custom port, fail2ban, and key-based entry with password disabled. Hope that's enough :) I'll give them a read anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Wisely done. I hope your ssh key has proper passphrase :) And remember to keep your Ubuntu up-to-date!